# Creating table change column's background color

Tags: css, html-table

I want to change background color when mouseover for COLUMN.
Is Javascript required or is CSS  enough?

What  should I change for  COLUMN's background color?

My Table:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1"> 
  <tr>
    <th width="169" scope="col">İsim</th>
    <th width="380" scope="col">Açıklama</th>
    <th width="138" scope="col">Telefon Numarası</th>
    <th width="158" scope="col">İl</th>
  </tr>

   <tr>
    <td><?=$data['u_isim']?></td>
    <td><?=$data['u_aciklama']?></td>
    <td><?=$data['u_tel']?></td>
    <td><?=$data['u_il']?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Similar to [this](http://pastebin.com/LwdYPgpi), but I can't be sure of this.**

Answer (score 0):

does your column are made with table or div?
if its in div, you can use hover like any link, but not all navigator support it.

otherwise, use jquery for best result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to happen on mouseover, you pretty much need Javascript for this. Using a `col:hover` selector in CSS isn't reliable at all.

Comment: No. I said you need JS for this.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how I got here after those years, but... I see there is still no solution.

In 2019 it's easy, you just need to pick an interesting [hex color](https://hexcol.com/) - in my example, it would be red (#ff0000).

The first step to do this in your code is adding a class to each td element like below:

```
<td class="example">
```

Then in css you are setting the hover, like this:

```
    .example:hover {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

That's it, should work to you.